# Cygwin XWin server: How to disable the creation of the "panel" window?

Tags: cygwin

A couple of months ago, I re-installed Cygwin on my Win7 machine. Since then, when clicking the XWin Server entry in the Start Menu, it not only starts the (familiar) X tray icon along with a `xterm` window (this is running in "rootless" mode), but also a frame-less, grey window with the same (slightly larger) X icon.

It is placed in the screen's top-left corner and on being clicked, it offers a small menu of applications to execute and to "Exit Cygwin/X". Its taskbar entry shows "panel" as its window title.

Since this "panel" window's functionality is duplicated in the tray icon's right-click menu (which has more options anyway), I am wondering how to suppress the start of this window.

I had a look at the `man` pages for `Xwin` and `XWinrc` as well as the files under `/etc/X11/xinit/`, but since I am new to X11 I might have missed something. The [Manpage of XWin](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/man1/XWin.1.html) and the [Configuring Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/configure.html) pages weren't helpful either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I launch my X Server with this: "XWin.exe -multiwindow"

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a much more lightweight solution than the one in the Cygwin default installation, which has the following (for me somewhat mysterious) command line: `C:\cygwin\bin\run.exe --quote /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c "cd; /usr/bin/startxwin"`.
I do wonder what I am missing when switching to this, much shorter version (other than not having an `xterm` window show up automatically)? Could you elaborate how you got to your solution, e.g. where can relevant documentation be found?

Comment: This worked for me: `c:\cygwin\bin\run.exe XWin -multiwindow -clipboard -silent-dup-error`

Answer (score 2):

I found fbpanel is here /etc/X11/xinit/startxwinrc
in the condition

```
if [ -f $HOME/.startxwinrc ] then
  exec $HOME/.startxwinrc
else
  ...
  /usr/bin/fbpanel
fi
```

so I've created $HOME/.startxwinrc with the only /usr/bin/xterm
(warning: line endings must be unix single LF)
it helped, no panel, only xterm window opens

Comment: +1 Thanks for that, this is another valid answer. One disadvantage I noted with this option though: Once I `exit` the *xterm* window, the whole server seems to shut down, at least the **X** icon in the systray disappears. Which might still be better than having the warnings "4 clients connected" when I click Exit in the systray menu given by my original installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a sleep command a the end of `$HOME/.startxwinrc`, and run your `xterm` in the background like this:

```
/usr/bin/xterm -ls &
sleep inf
```

It should avoid the whole session closing when the initial `xterm` closes.